# Problem with pyodbc (Macbook M1) connecting to MS-SQL server

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, openssl, pyodbc

I'm writing a python script to fetch data from a MS-SQL server.
When running the script I get this message:
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (10054) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I'm using:

- python 3.10.9
- MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a)
- Apple M1 Pro
- pyodbc 4.0.39
- Openssl 3.1.0

I have installed pyodbc with this command: pip install --pre --no-binary :all: pyodbc

This is part of the script I'm working on:

```py
import pyodbc
import csv
import boto3
    
# Credentials for SQL server
server = "1.1.1.1"
database = "db1"
username = "user"
password = "password"

# ODBC connection to MS-SQL server
cnxn_str = pyodbc.connect(
        "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};"
        + "SERVER="
        + server
        + ";DATABASE="
        + database
        + ";UID="
        + username
        + ";PWD="
        + password
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)`
```

Anybody any thoughts how I get this working?

I've tried several settings regarding Openssl (CipherString and MinProtocol), but can't get it working.

Comment: If you think this error is to do with connection encryption... ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server had a [breaking change to use encryption by default](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228). It presents a couple of options for you, each with different security implications.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea but it works for me:

```
ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 0):

[The article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/known-issues-in-this-version-of-the-driver?view=sql-server-ver16) from MS clear explain there could be an issue for some macos users. The solution is indeed to create a symlink after installing OpenSSL.

```
    rm -rf $(brew --prefix)/opt/openssl
version=$(ls $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/openssl@1.1 | grep "1.1")
ln -s $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/openssl@1.1/$version $(brew --prefix)/opt/openssl
```